# Make prelude C-a go to the absolute beginning of the line

Tags: motion, prelude

Emacs [prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude) "smartens" `C-a` by rebinding it to "crux-move-beginning-of-line"

My muscle memory likes the vanilla emacs setting better, where
C-a moves point to the absolute beginning of the line.

How do turn off this specific prelude "smarts". ?

Comment: I tried googling https://www.google.com/search?q=make+prelude+C-a+go+to+the+absolute+beginning+of+the+line&oq=make+prelude+C-a+go+to+the+absolute+beginning+of+the+line&aqs=chrome..69i57.3373j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Please look at the [Emacs manual on keybindings](https://www.google.com/search?q=emacs+manual+keybindings&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

Comment: the emacs manual on keybindings are not ideal when you're dealing with prelude way of doing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use that:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-a") 'move-beginning-of-line)
```

Since this is defined on [prelude-mode](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude/blob/f7d5d68d432319bb66a5f9410d2e4eadd584f498/core/prelude-mode.el#L46), you can alternatively redefine this directly for this minor mode map:

```
(define-key prelude-mode-map (kbd "C-a") 'move-beginning-of-line)
```

If you don't want write any additional setup on your init file, as ultimate alternative you can just disable `prelude-mode` by `M-x prelude-mode`, but if you are using prelude I don't see this is as good thing, but you can anyway.

Comment: This does not go beginning of the line if the line is commented out